# How to add line break with Media Queries?

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to add a line break if the screen width is smaller than X.

Half of the text should stay on the next line, instead of just one word, on smaller screen width.

---

**Normal view on big screens:**

[image: Big screens]

**Normal view on smaller screens:**

[image: Smaller screens]

**Wanted result on smaller screens:**

[image: Wanted result]

*Thinner text is not related*

---

I'm looking for a way to do it with CSS.

Comment: You cannot add any tags with CSS. Instead, you should specify the formatting desired. What the question now describes seems to say that text should line-wrap as needed, which is what happens automatically anyway if you don’t force line breaks.

Comment: I'm aware of it. The problem is that it wraps the text word by word, while I want the words "Web" & "design" to be on the same line if there's enough space.

Comment: You should clarify the question by editing the question itself. Even the title is now misleading.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use @media queries with `span` element and turn them to `display: block;` as they are inline by default...

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s94es/)</kbd> *(Resize the fiddle window)*

```
div {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    div span:last-of-type {
        display: block;
        color: #f00;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    div span:nth-of-type(2) {
        display: block;
        color: #00f;
    }
}
```

Explanation: Here, I've simply wrapped each word with the `span` element which is *inline* by default.. So what I do is, I turn them to `display: block;` if the screen resolution is less than some `px`.

You can make these flexible by applying `display: block;` and `display: inline-block;` whichever suits your requirements.

If screen size is maximum of `400px`

[image]

---

If screen size is maximum of `300px`

[image]

Changing colors so that you can see the effect.

Comment: Very good. Clear answer and clear fiddle, but you could've used classes or IDs instead of selectors. Otherwise, great answer, thanks.

Comment: @Claudio Yea, I didn't use them cuz sometimes people pick the codes and paste them straight away, if by chance the classes or ids duplicated, they will get some unexpected results, so I keep the basic selector always :)

Answer (score 9):

Add the `br` in your code, hide it using css initially and make it `display: inline` in media queries when the width meets your requirement

http://jsfiddle.net/LnECr/1/

```
br{ display: none; }
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .break2 { display: inline }
}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
    br { display: inline }
}
```

Many different ways this can be done, I am using `br` because you asked for `br`

Comment: Or wrap 'web design' on a `<span>` and toggle display:block in media queries.

Comment: enapupe has the best answer

Comment: @enapupe should be top answer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a `<br />` tag. Use CSS `white-space:nowrap` instead.

Like this:

```
<h1>Creative <span class="wrap">Web Design</span></h1>

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
span.wrap {
white-space:nowrap;
}

}
```

Comment: I also only say "I wouldn't use.." because I don't personally like to add elements to the DOM if it's not necessary.

Comment: Right, but in this case it is necessary as you have also added a span. I also think that the width of the text is not the width of the screen or else there is no need to add anything

Comment: @Huangism agreed! I just find that a `<br />` is what I consider a hard element vs `span` a soft element. `span` by itself doesn't do anything, until styled. Either way, I gave your answer a +1 because it's correct.

Comment: I actually think span is the better way to go but it might not have the flexibility in some cases as brs